# Alloy YUI - Tab retain after Portal refresh / Submit some action

Tags: liferay, alloy-ui

I followed this link http://alloyui.com/examples/tabview/ for Tab view.I am having 3 tabs and each tab contains unique form.It can submit also.After clicked 3rd Tab and submitting the concern form in 3rd Tab it is redirecting to 1St Tab only  always.I want to retain same Tab only after submitting form.what to do?

```
<script>
 YUI().use(
  'aui-tabview',
 function(Y) {
 new Y.TabView(
   {
    srcNode: '#myTab'
  }
).render();
}
);
</script>
<div id="myTab">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab #1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab #2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab #3</a></li>
  </ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane">
   <form id="abc1">......</form>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">
    <form id="abc2">....</form>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">
    <form id="abc3">....</form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pass the index of the [activeTab](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.TabView.html#method_getActiveTab) through the render/response phases and use [selectChild method](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.TabView.html#method_selectChild) when the view is rendered after the submission is completed.

Comment: Bless your answer! The only answer on the Internet saying how to switch between tabs!!!